SQL Anywhere 9 Finding Duplicates
Ok, so I asked this question before but I received no replies so I'm trying a slightly different way.
We have the following script that finds duplicate patients in a database...
SELECT count((Pquery.Last_Name || '_' || Pquery.First_Name|| '_' || Pquery.Date_Of_Birth)) as PatientCount,

(Pquery.Last_Name || '_' || Pquery.First_Name|| '_' || Pquery.Date_Of_Birth) as PatientString

FROM
(SELECT Name AS Last_Name, Other_Names AS First_Name, DOB as Date_Of_Birth
FROM dba.patient) as Pquery
GROUP BY PatientString
HAVING PatientCount > 1
ORDER BY PatientString ASC, PatientCount DESC;
OUTPUT TO 'c:\duplicates.csv'

The script works fine and pulls the duplicate patients.
One customer has asked if we can provide additional information such as the patient ID number.
The problem I have is that with the script above, if I tell it to select the patient ID number as PID, it fails to match some patients as it is then trying to match the patient ID and not all entries contain a PID. For example...
If I run the script without selecting the PID, I would get the following results...
2_A_Patient_01011980 2_B_Patient_01022010 2_C_Patient_21101999
The script picks 3 patients that have 2 duplicate records each because it matched the last name, first name and DOB.
If I ask it to select the patient ID, I could get the following...
2_A_Patient_01011980_12345678
This is because the script finds a match with Patient A with the first name, last name, DOB and PID but no PID match on Patient B and Patient C so didn't pick them as duplicates even though we know there are two duplicate records.
The issue is the site we are working with has over 13000 duplicate patient records but they have asked us to include patient ID's and address information.
Is there any way I can pull the list of duplicate patients using my original script and then pull the patient ID and address using the information from that script?
I'm not a scripting expert and we don't have any SQL knowledge in house apart from the little bits I've cobbled together myself.
The company that support the app we support will not provide scripting support for customer scripts and won't provide scripting support for obsolete s/w versions which is in use on the customer site.
Thanks
Detailed as above.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

table structure? sample data?  There is such limited information provided, that's probably why your earlier question wasn't answered. Provide the script to create that table with all relevant columns, then provide some sample data (scrubbed for anything private) but that data must contain both duplicated and not duplicated patients - and lastly provide the "expected result" we should locate from the sample data (i.e. this expected result would include the pid column).

Try using an aggregate function instead of traditional grouping e.g.
SELECT 
    *
FROM (
   SELECT
        PID
      , Name AS Last_Name
      , Other_Names AS First_Name
      , DOB as Date_Of_Birth
      , count(*) over(partition by PatientString) as count_of
    FROM dba.patient) as Pquery
    ) d
WHERE count_of > 1

The advantage here is that you can output as many columns as you need from the source data as this approach retains complete row integrity. Note the partition by within the over clause achieves the needed "grouping" but the source data is not summarised as happens when using group by.
